# Custom Circular line OutputStream in Java

Tags: java

I need to create Circular OutputStream that limits the max number of lines and when it's full - starts writing with the oldest value. But I have no idea what to start with.

Comment: Do you mean a BufferedOutputStream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)?  If not, in what way does the desired behavior differ?

Comment: You can extend [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) and keep a buffer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand how a circular buffer works:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Then create an implementation, or find one that already exists.
If you do it yourself just create an array of strings and use two pointers for writing and reading.

A Queue limited in size will behave quite similar to your circular buffer if you think of overwrite protection. This is e.g. the case in the [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).